# Expand user model when fetching user data from Active Directory

Tags: django, django-models, active-directory, ldap

I am using [django_python3_ldap](https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap) to connect to active directory. I can import users and sync them, making sure that the users that are already in the AD can log into the app without needing separate credentials.

However, issue is that in addition to username, first_name, last_name and email, I want to import phone and office location from the AD. However, merely adding these fields causes the sync to break. I read from various tutorials that I should *extend* the Django user-model, but the import used by the library does not support extended one-to-one values. I am not confident in entirely replacing the django user model, so is there any good way to expand the user model to include these fields?

Comment: Maybe using an extended *copy* of the base user model ?

Comment: What do you mean by extended copy?

Comment: I mean creating a custom user-model based on a copy of the base Django model, so that you can customize it according to your needs - instead of extending/modifying the base model.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly, you mean creating a new model that inherits the Django default user model and adding new fields to that, then replacing default model with this new model?

Comment: Yes that is the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ErickLavault I was able to solve this issue. For those who come here later, here is the way I did.

Create a new model and have it inherit AbstractUser. Then I just added new fields I wanted to it.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    office = models.CharField('office', max_length=40, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField('phone_number', max_length=40, blank=True)
```

Then I substituded default model with this new model in `settings.py`by adding following line before LDAP section

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.User'
```

Authentication being the app name and User the model I want to use

This allowed me to keep same functionality as the base Django user model, while allowing me to expand the class properties the way I needed.